# Unit test that checks property names match xaml element names. Wpf, caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, caliburn.micro

I'm using [caliburn micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) to bind properties in a ViewModel to elements in the xaml.  The binding only works if you type the property name correctly in the view.  I'm writing a unit test that verifies the match(sense this won't be caught at compile time).  Here's what I have:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void LockQuarterViewModel_property_names_should_match_xaml_element_names()
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(RollLockQuarterViewModel).GetProperties(); 
        RollLockQuarterView view = new RollLockQuarterView();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            var element = view.FindName(property.Name);   // eg  "UserWideBlockOut" checkbox.
            Assert.IsNotNull(element);
        }
    }
```

This seems to work for things like checkboxes:

```
<CheckBox Name="UserWideBlockOut"/>
```

But it won't work for things like user controls where "Binding" is used:

```
<cc:YearQuarterSelector Margin="5,0,0,0" YearQuarter="{Binding CurrentYearQuarter}" IsEnabled="False" />
```

So 2 Questions:
1) How would I test the user controls where the binding is done with the "Binding" keyword?
2) Is there any recommendations in my approach to testing this? Better ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Binding expressions could be **very** complex. You shouldn't test them this way.

Comment: @Dennis, Is there a better way?  thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad way to unit test, it makes them brittle. You are "coding against stupidity" which can seriously bloat your codebase. This is the sort of thing that should only go wrong in dev and as such should be caught before production.

Comment: I have already fixed a number of bugs where certain fields are not saving.  This is because re-factors have been done and they forgot to change names in the xaml.  We currently don't have the resources to regression test each individual field after each 3 week sprint.

Comment: When the field name changes after rework will you have time to rework the tests that fail? I promise you this will end in tears. Your are testing implementation details that are supposed to be free to be changed Organically with each UI revision. Your test will be extremely brittle and will become dependent on the public implementation of both your view and viewModel as well as a specific style of implementation because that is ultimately what your testing. Any change in both these places will break every associated test.

Comment: If the tests fail then we will know that there's a bug.  So that's a good thing.  I'm happy to see a test fail after re-work...that means the re-work was done incorrectly.